# Regex to match all '&' before first '?'

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I want to do "zipzam&&&?&&&?&&&" -> "zipzam%26%26%26?&&&?&&&". I can do that without regex many different ways, but it'd cleanup things a tad bit if I could do it with regex.

Thanks

Edit: "zip=zam&&&=?&&&?&&&" -> "zip=zam%26%26%26=?&&&?&&&" should make things a little clearer.

Edit: "zip=zam=&=&=&=?&&&?&&&" -> "zip=zam=%26=%26=%26=?&&&?&&&" should make things clearer.

However, theses are just examples. I still want to replace *all* '&' before the first '?' no matter where the '&' are before the first '?' and no matter if the '&' are consecutive or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
"zip=zam=&=&=&=?&&&?&&&".replace(/^[^?]+/, function(match) { return match.replace(/&/g, "%26"); });
```

Comment: @Gumbo I think your last one does the trick. Let me double check for a bit.

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks. The last one does it. And, if there's no '?' present, it turns all the & to %26, which is what I want too.

Comment: nice simple semi-recursion solution, better presented than my efforts +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

you need negative lookbehinds which are tricky to replicate in JS, but fortunately there are ways and means:

```
var x = "zipzam&&&?&&&?&&&";

x.replace(/(&+)(?=.*?\?)/,function ($1) {for(var i=$1.length, s='';i;i--){s+='%26';} return s;})
```

commentary: this works because it's *not* global. The first match is therefore a given, and the trick of replacing all of the matching "&" chars 1:1 with "%26" is achieved with the function loop

---

edit: a solution for unknown groupings of "&" can be achieved simply (if perhaps a little clunkily) with a little modification. The basic pattern for replacer methods is infinitely flexible.

```
var x = "zipzam&foo&bar&baz?&&&?&&&";

var f = function ($1,$2)
{
  return $2 + ($2=='' || $2.indexOf('?')>-1 ? '&' : '%26')
}

x.replace(/(.*?)&(?=.*?\?)/g,f)
```

Comment: This seems to produce the result I want:
alert("zip=zam&&&=?&&&?&&&".replace(/(&+)(?=.*?\?)/, encodeURIComponent));

However, am I missing something?

Comment: @Will - WFM, produces "zipzam%26%26%26?&&&?&&&"

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting different results.  I'll bow to you guys.

Comment: @Shadow - nope, that could be a clean solution for you. The encodeURIComponent method will achieve the same result as the anon method above in this case, since the first argument to the method is still going to be the match, you gain built-in handling, but lose some flexibility. It's a good solution

Comment: @Will - I'm just running this on an html page in my editor, can't imagine why you'd see anything different?

Comment: @annakata Thanks. However, there's a problem. The regex only works if the &s are right next to each other. I want to match *all* & before the first '?' no matter where there are.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if it might. Perhaps your question could clarify that, but nonetheless it's easy enough to extend too (see edit)

Comment: Yes, clarified the question and thanks.  My fault for not being clear. I didn't expect my examples to distract from the title. Will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^[^?]*&[^?]*\?
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would use this pattern to achieve the goal,

Answer (score 1):

In this case regexes are really not the most appropiate things to use. A simple search for the first index of '?' and then replacing each '&' character would be best. However, if you really want a regex then this should do the job.

```
(?:.*?(&))*?\?
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this one, I think:

```
^[^?]*(&+?)\?
```

Comment: @Will, the idea that i thought is to match the "&" in a group.

Answer (score 1):

This close enough to what you are after:-

```
alert("zipzam&&&?&&&?&&&".replace(/^([^&\?]*)(&*)\?/, function(s, p, m)
{
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) p += '%26';
return  p +'?';
}));
```

Comment: I think I'm getting some incorrect results from my testing.  I'm removing all my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP only wants to match ampersands before the first question mark, slightly modifying Michael Borgwardt's answer gives me this Regex which appears to be appropriate :

```
^[^?&]*(\&+)\?
```

Replace all matches with "%26"

This will not match **zipzam&&abc?&&&?&&&** because the first "?" does not have an ampersand immediately before it.